# Triple integral - volume of a solid body

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Suppose the body $D$ is bounded by the $xy-$plane, and the surfaces $z=2y\ $ and $y=4-x^2$.
On a side note, I think the second surface is called a ***parabolic cylinder***, is that right?

What is the volume $V$ of this body?

I calculated it and I got $V = 512/15$

Is that correct?

[image: picture1]

Comment: How did you set up your integral?

Comment: My inner-most integral is by $z$, where $z$ goes from $0$ to $2y$. Then by $y$, where $y$ goes from $0$ to $4-x^2$, finally (outer-most) by $x$ which goes from $-2$ to $2$. I don't know (yet) how to type this in MathJax.

Comment: $\int_{-2}^2\int_0^{4-x^2}\int_0^{2y}\ dz\ dy\ dx$  That is the correct set-up.

Comment: @DougM Yes, that's what I have.

Comment: I am getting the same result!

Comment: @DougM OK, thank you.

Comment: What about the name of the 2nd surface. Is this indeed a parabolic cylinder? On the web I am finding somewhat different equations for parabolic cylinders?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_1:=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:z=0\}$, $S_2:=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:z=2y\}$ and $S_3:=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:y=4-x^2\}$. Now define $\tilde S_k$ the compact and convex region of $S_k$ bounded by the other surfaces for $k\in\{1,2,3\}$, then

$$
\tilde S_1=\{(x,y,0)\in \mathbb{R}^3:|x|\leqslant 2\,\land\, 0\leqslant y\leqslant 4-x^2\}\\
\tilde S_2=\{(x,y,2y)\in \mathbb{R}^3:|x|\leqslant 2\,\land\, 0\leqslant y\leqslant 4-x^2\}\\
\tilde S_3=\{(x,4-x^2,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:|x|\leqslant 2\,\land\, 0\leqslant z\leqslant 8-2x^2\}
$$
Thus the region is
$$
R=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:|x|\leqslant 2\,\land\, 0\leqslant y\leqslant 4-x^2\,\land\, 0\leqslant z\leqslant 2y\}
$$
Therefore
$$
\int_{R}dxdydz=\int_{-2}^2\int_{0}^{4-x^2}\int_{0}^{2y}dzdydx=\int_{-2}^2\int_{0}^{4-x^2}2ydydx\\
=\int_{-2}^2(4-x^2)^2 dx=\frac{512}{15}.
$$